# How can we call event handler asynchronously for an event

Tags: c#-3.0

Is there a way to  subscribe to an event and handle it asynchronously using the event+=EventHandler
syntax or is there any workaround to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

The event/delegate system calls each of the subscribed event handles synchronously on the thread the fires the event. To make the event handler processing be done asynchrounously, it has to be part of the function that you subscribe to the event.